# What size beam should I use for an adult swingset? I want a roughly 12' span to support 3 swings that can be used by adults

Tags: beam, swing

I'm planning to build a swingset for my grandkids, but their parents and I want to be able to play on it with them. I plan to use an A-frame structure with 4"x4" legs and a 12' cross piece beam. What size cross piece beam should I use?

Comment: I would think a beam made from three 2x10s or better 2x12s if made out of wood.  3x3 steel might be better.  My cow lift will hold plus 1000 pounds of moving cow.  It is the swinging weight that is the problem.

Comment: 2 or 3 inch gas pipe

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to use wood, as I'm not a welder. When my kids were little I used a 4x6 and it lasted until they were in HS, when it finally cracked. When you say 2.10s or 2x12s (plural) do you mean two planks bolted together?